# Touches Began method not called in my custom UISearchBar class

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, xcode4

I am adding a UISearchBar which was initialized using a Custom Class to a UIView. And I have overridden the touchesBegan() method.

And I have enabled user interaction in the UISearchBar. But still touchesBegan() method does not fire when clicked on the search bar.

Any Idea why touchesBegan() function is not called? 
It'll be great if anyone could help me out.

Answer (score 2):

you have to make sure to set the delegate for UISearchBar. In doing this, in your .h file, type  after UIViewController. Then in your nib file, make sure to connect your searchbar to the name of your searchbar found in the Referencing Outlets section. Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have set the custom class in Interface Builder as UISearchBar?

Comment: Yes I have... I have associated my search bar with the custom class i created.

Comment: Have you overwritten any other methods?
Try to make a new custom class and only override the touchesBegan: method.

Comment: Please post some sample-code, or answer your own question if you have solved it.